# How to have PHP and mod_wsgi python app on the same domain?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, python, mod-wsgi

I am using apache with mod_wsgi (python3) on ubuntu 12.04.

I have a python app (bottle) which is at www.mysite.com/

In my python app I have routes like www.mysite.com/abbb?q=blab

I would like a path www.mysite.com/forum to resolve to a php app (simple machine forums)

Ideally I would like to use apache to handle the forum part and pass it to php (instead of coding it in the python app). Don't know if it's possible.

I'm new to this, I have read https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive but I don't understand how to use it.

Here is my apache conf for the mod_wsgi app, I don't know how to specify the PHP portion.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.ex.com
ServerAlias ex.com *.ex.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]

WSGIDaemonProcess ex user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/ex/app.wsgi


<Directory /var/www/vhosts/ex>
    WSGIProcessGroup ex
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like:

```
Alias /forum "/var/www/forum/"

<Directory "/var/www/forum/">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I just had to change Deny from all to Allow from all. Worked like a charm.